# A question about Thread.Sleep inside backgroundworker

Tags: backgroundworker

As far as I understand backgroundworker in .Net runs on a separate threat than in GUI. And Thread.Sleep is not recommended since it freezes the GUI.

Now if one uses Thread.Sleep **inside backgroundworker's DoWork**, would GUI freeze or this time Sleep will only sleep the BW's thread? Is it still not recommended?

(I tried to give 1 second pauses inside DoWork by Thread.Sleep(1000) seems it doesnt interfere with GUI. Is there another way to give pause inside BW rather than Thread.Sleep? await Task needs sync method which BW is not:()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if one uses Thread.Sleep inside backgroundworker's DoWork, would GUI freeze or this time Sleep will only sleep the BW's thread?

`Thread.Sleep`, like all other methods, runs on the current thread. So `Thread.Sleep` causes the current thread to sleep. If it's called from the BGW's `DoWork`, then it will cause the BGW's thread to sleep.

> Is there another way to give pause inside BW rather than Thread.Sleep?

No, but you could [replace the `BackgroundWorker` completely with `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html), and then you could use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Do you think there would be any advantage to use Task with await instead of BW with sleep in terms of performance ?

Comment: @cm64: In a Desktop app, it wouldn't be noticeable. The `Task.Run` approach enables `async` code, so it uses fewer threads, and more importantly, prepares the code for future `async` work.